# Something happened and the Windows 8.1 Preview couldn't be installed. Please try again

Tags: upgrade, windows-8.1

Windows 8 Pro, on the way to upgrading to 8.1, got a cryptic error, steps as follows: - clicked on the 'update to windows 8.1' windows store tile - 'downloading' message showed up - error! 'Something happened and the Windows 8.1 Preview couldn't be installed. Please try again'

not very informative...

Comment: Answer here, sorry no rep: Turns out windows store didn't like my UK English en-gb language input setting for some reason. Solution for me was to install en-us language pack and make it the main input language, here is how: 1. hit the windows key, type 'language', select 'add language' 2. now you will be adding English US (as mentioned I only had English UK.) What this does is install the English US language pack and places it on the languages list. 3. make sure English US is first on the list. That will make it your system main input language. Now back to the store and it will download

Comment: Please don't tell me you are installing the Preview when the GA/RTM build is freely available.

Comment: nope, tried to install RTM and got the error. No preview involved. Why -1 btw?

Comment: Because the question is vague and offers very little details.  You don't even tell us what error you got.  The title says "Windows 8.1 Preview" which is the reason I asked.