# Error in Windows 10 setup: "Something happened"

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I downloaded the Microsoft `Media Creation Tool` to create an ISO file for Windows 10. After selecting the version I want and clicking `Next` I got:

[image: Something Happened]

I can click `Close` and the program finishes without doing anything.

In [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/948532/8-1-to-10-setup-something-happened-setup-has-failed-to-validate-the-product) the second text at least gives some more details.

In the diagerr.xml I can see the following error:

```
CSetupPlatform::ResurrectNewSystem: 
Failure: Win32Exception: \\?\C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\NewSystem.dat: 
The system cannot find the file specified. [0x00000002] __cdecl    
UnBCL::FileStream::FileStream(const class UnBCL::String *,enum 
UnBCL::FileMode,enum UnBCL::FileAccess,enum UnBCL::FileShare,unsigned long)
```

Maybe the fact that the version of Windows I'm doing this on does not match the one I want to download has something to do with it?

Comment: what you have here seems different to the linked one, . http://superuser.com/questions/661978/something-happened-and-the-windows-8-1-preview-couldnt-be-installed-please-try?s=4|1.9287  For a something happens somethig happens (no error text), it might be the regional settings thing.  and of course the version stuff has to match, home to home, pro to pro and enterprise no.

Comment: @Psycogeek - They give me the option of `Create installation media for another PC` nowhere does it say it was to be the same `language, architecture, and edition`. In my case neither language nor edition match but if that is the problem, it should just tell me.

Comment: It should do a lot of things :-) I was just relaying to you that people have discovered that changing the regional settings before the upgrade fixed that particular error for some people, to have it be set for american english or something? It is assumed they switched it right back once they got past these problems.  we dont know yet how many things would cause that same error, because many people just changed the method they do it with completly.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Are you using the original __`Windows 8`__? Windows 10 isn't compatible with Windows 8. Go to the Windows Store and upgrade to Windows 8.1

Comment: @Joseph - I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 to run the `Media Creation Tool` that's the only English Windows version I have available. All other machines have Windows 7 Simplified Chinese which I can not read.

Comment: Windows Server isn't compatible. There isn't a Windows 10 Server / Windows Server 2016 yet.

Comment: @Joseph That doesn’t mean it cannot be used to create ISOs. // +1 because the message is hilarious.

Comment: @DanielB That is true. You could still make ISOs. Oops, I didn't see the beginning of your question. Try elevating the tool. `Right Click` > `Run as Administrator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Download Tool, you can access ISO images directly. Because Microsoft tries to force Windows users to use the Download Tool, you’ll have to change your browser’s user agent to something different, like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
```

Then, go to the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and select the appropriate ISO. It will contain both Home and Pro.

Be careful about the first selection (Plain/N/KN etc). It absolutely has to match your current installation, or upgrading will not be possible. If you’re only interested in a clean installation, it’s not really important.

Comment: I think that would be a great idea! I upvoted.

Comment: Good idea, but that pages doesn't allow me to pick 32 or 64bit and it doesn't allow me to change the language. I could change `en-us` in the URL to `zh-TW` and hope I get the correct version, but who knows.

Comment: That’s not true. It asks for the product version (Plain/N/KN/Single Language), language (English and whatnot) and then finally takes you to a page containing links to both x86 and x64 ISO images.

Comment: You are right, I just saw the first page and didn't follow the next steps, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running the `Media Creation Tool` on a Windows 7 with the same language and bitness as the ISO I wanted to download. This meant I had to get the help of some Chinese speaker but the tool worked fine and downloaded the ISO for me.

Comment: I got [the same problem](http://superuser.com/q/1022247/282033) with that tool too.